# Where to buy a 4-inch toilet flapper in North America?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I am having the toughest time finding the right replacement toilet flush flapper that fits. The pipe in the water tank is really wide, and the old flapper has the diameter of 4 inch, and 3 inch wide between the hinge attachment (see picture). I have searched online with Amazon, eBay, and specific toilet equipment companies, and looking at the models in person at Homedepot and Walmart, and still couldn't find one. Please advice where I can find a model of that size specification. [image]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
Edits: Adding more pictures for information
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please look inside the toilet tank and write in a comment (or add as an edit to your post) all the info stamped into the inside tank wall. At minimum it should have the name of the manufacturer.

Comment: Added pictures as suggested.

Comment: That is a 3" flapper. They can be purchased at lowes, that is where i bought mine.

Answer (score 1):

That's a Kohler Bancroft 4633. Here's where you can buy a **[[replacement flapper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LEM5RLK)]**.

[image: Flapper]

Here's a schematic of the **[Kohler Bancroft 4633.](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/kohlertoiletparts-bancroft.html)**

Comment: The closest I can find in Canada is - https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.3-14-inch-flapper-class-5-for-2-piece-toilets.1001043344.html, is this compatible?